# What is the derivative of $\dot{\theta^2}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\dot{\theta^2}) =?  2\dot{\theta}\ddot{\theta}$$

is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about elementary calculus, and not a physics question.

Comment: Why does this have two answers? People looking for cheap and dirty internet points?

Comment: @0celo7 This question does not deserve an answer?

Comment: @Carl You should check your questions for typos.

Comment: *"Why does this have two answers?"* - the question wasn't closed fast enough?

Comment: @algolejos It's off topic, and blatantly so.

Comment: @0celo7 Unfortunately questions like this get answers all the time. It's a matter of how fast they get through people's review queue. I rarely even look at my close vote queue because of how daunting that forty some-odd number looks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, that's right. It's hard to be more explicit than that, since it's just the chain rule. As a product,
$$\frac{d}{dt} \dot{\theta}^2 = \frac{d}{dt}(\dot{\theta}\dot{\theta}) = \dot{\theta}\ddot{\theta} + \dot{\theta}\ddot{\theta} = 2\dot{\theta}\ddot{\theta}.$$

Comment: Watch out! Look at the upper dot.
It does not says ${\dot \theta}^2$, but $\dot {\theta^2}$

Comment: Oh no! You're right. Although I suspect this is what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

${d \over dt} \theta = \dot \theta$

So what you are asking is basically
${d^2 \over dt^2} \theta^2$

First, ${d \over dt} \theta^2 = \dot{\theta^2} = 2 \theta \dot \theta$

Second, ${d \over dt}(\dot{\theta^2}) = {d \over dt} (2 \theta \dot \theta) = 2 \dot \theta^2 + 2 \theta \ddot \theta$

Comment: No, d^2/dt^2 (x^2) is not the same as d/dt ((dx/dt)^2).

Comment: @HarryWilson That's exactly mypoint!

Comment: Though that might not have been the notation OP used (as you pointed out in the comment above), I think he *means* to ask about  d/dt ((dx/dt)^2). It certainly is ambiguous.

Comment: @HarryWilson It's not ambiguous. Math is an exact science. It is not subject to interpretations.

Comment: While that is true, notation is not exact... When I write $\sin^{-1}(x)$ do I mean $\text{arcsin}(x)$ or do I mean $1/sin(x)$? So tell me ... What is $\frac {d} {d x} \sin^{-1}(x)$? Ambiguous, no?